# How to resize detached window to screen size

Tags: windows, windows-10

I work with Adobe products in a daily basis as it is my job. One of Adobe's best features is that almost all of their products are made from detachable windows. This allows me to put one window in my second display and have a better workflow.

In MacOS, you just double-click on the top bar of the window and it automatically resizes the detached window to the screen size, but in W10 I have to manually resize it and it ends up being a time-killing process. Only the main screen can resize to screen size with double-click.

In W10, as far as I know, it happens with every program. I don't know if W10 has a built-in function that I am unable to find for this.

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2021/03/sizewindowexe-changes-size-of-window.html.

Comment: @user1292580 this script doesn't work, looks like it's bugged. :(

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a Maximise/restore button, top right of every window.

Centre icon,
Maximise  [image]
and Restore  [image]

There are a slew of other ways to achieve this - see https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/147622-how-maximize-restore-app-window-windows-10-a.html

Comment: This is only applicable to main windows. Secondary windows have this option greyed out.

Comment: Ah, OK, then Windows is still cheating … I thought they'd stopped doing that. What version of Adobe are you using?

Comment: Latest, 2021. It happens with other programs and almost all of them, could be something programmers decide to disable?

Comment: Specifically which windows have this feature disabled? I'd expect the Workspace stuff, Histogram, History etc to not have this function - they don't in Mac either.

Comment: RN I'm with AE. Every window I detach can't be resized. PP does the same.

Comment: I'd be asking the company for a Mac. Colour management is far easier too, **especially** if you use multiple displays ;)

Comment: I'm a freelancer since I've dropped from the company I worked on. Workflow is great on MacOS and I miss that :/

Comment: Then consider total cost of ownership against the tax you can claim back on a larger initial outlay ;)) Sorry, I've never used Adobe on PC, though I did do a lot of pro audio on one in the mid 2000's when Win was beating Mac for raw processing power. I kept a Mac for graphics work right through, until I could afford a better one by the end of the decade. I have a house full of [now old] Mac Pros, still really good for colour repro work as well as audio. My only remaining 'PC' is a Win10 instance running in Parallels on one of those old cheesegraters;)

Comment: I checked with some of the guys in chat at graphics.se & they say it works for them. I'd contact Adobe [or get that Mac you know you want;))) Wish you luck.

Comment: Well, seems like there's a problem of mine :( I studied the option of buying a Mac for motion graphics design but I'm not in the right economical situation for this and my workstation is powerful enough for this tasks and more. Even tho, I appreciate your help and recommendations :)